# Chrome Extension - How to access webcam and Audio at intervals?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webcam

I have a chrome extension I am using that I want to integrate with my webcam to do some funky computer vision and audio ML stuff.

usuauly i'd do something liek this,

for audio,

```
<audio id="player" controls></audio>
<script>
  const player = document.getElementById('player');

  const handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    if (window.URL) {
      player.srcObject = stream;
    } else {
      player.src = stream;
    }
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
      .then(handleSuccess);
</script>
```

for webcam

```
<video autoplay></video>

<script>
const constraints = {
  video: true
};

const video = document.querySelector('video');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
  then((stream) => {video.srcObject = stream});
</script>
```

With a chrome extension, would the best pathway be to use the background.js file - I am struggling to find any documentation or information about how I could do it with that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The background script might refuse to grant the access as it's not a visible page. In that case I would use a content script to add an iframe in the tab, pointing to a html file in the extension, exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). Inside that iframe you would have a standard extension page where you can use any `chrome` API.

Comment: @wOxxOm So essentially, use the popup for the chrome extension to serve the html code?

Comment: A popup inside the page as a DOM element, yes.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried your suggestion of embedding an extension page in an iframe in any tab. If I open the page directly in the browser I can access user media. If that page is loaded in an iframe, it seems it cannot access user media. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an option page (HTML file which lives in extension directory) and have camera/audio permissions granted there once. after this, you can use these APIs directly in [background scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#background_script)

Here is the [example](https://github.com/fxnoob/Hand-in-the-air) of doing so.

Comment: Brilliant - granted once, so each time user logs back on, still granted i assume? Thanks!

Comment: yes. it is becuase user grants permission on chrome extension page. thereafter you can access camera/audio APIs in background script without asking for permission ever again.

Comment: @Mitya Right! it depends on the workflow. let's say if user block the mic, you would show some message or redirect user to allow permissions somewhere in options pages right?

Comment: Yes, if they block it I suppose you'll need to show them a message and encourage them to unblock it - via the options page, or via the browser's own tools (which track which domains you've allowed/blocked media on.)