# Microphone permission for chrome extension using angular

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions, microphone

I am building one chrome extension for text to speech conversion and translation
But I m not able to get permission in chrome extension. How can i get microphone permission using angular.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Extension - How to access webcam and Audio at intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63656707/chrome-extension-how-to-access-webcam-and-audio-at-intervals)

Comment: Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63656707/chrome-extension-how-to-access-webcam-and-audio-at-intervals & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991321/chrome-extension-getusermedia-throws-notallowederror-failed-due-to-shutdown

Comment: @cameck I am looking for angular

Comment: oh I gotcha. There shouldn’t be any difference though, you can adapt the native syntax to your Angular app.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/63656707/…

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/63656707/… this link have answer but i m not  able tounderstand what he exactly want us to do

Comment: @cameck i implemented it thank you so much

Comment: That’s great to hear ! @JayParmar