# getting `DOMException: Failed due to shutdown` when trying to record stream from screen+microphone

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, getusermedia

I am building an extension that records my screen and microphone audio as well.

**Overview:**

I have content.js which tries to get the access of `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({...` in the succession I send message to the background.js which again tries to access `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({...` over here I am recording the audio stream. In addition to this, I have popup.html which have a start button on clicking the button I am recording the screen. But in the full process I am getting the error `DOMException: Failed due to shutdown`.

Also, I am aware there have been questions on the above error (the famous one [Chrome Extension - getUserMedia throws "NotAllowedError: Failed due to shutdown"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991321/chrome-extension-getusermedia-throws-notallowederror-failed-due-to-shutdown)) but didn’t help me much.

**content.js**

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
   audio: { echoCancellation: true }
   })
    .then((e) => { chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ from: 'success' })})
    .catch((e) => {console.log(e);});
```

**Background.js**

```
var recorder = null;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message) {
   if(message.from === 'success') {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: { echoCancellation: true }
      })
      .then((e) => { 
                var chunks = [];
                var options = {
                    mimeType: 'audio/webm',
                };
                recorder = new MediaRecorder(e, options);
                recorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
                    if (event.data.size > 0) {
                        chunks.push(event.data);
                    }
                };
                recorder.onstop = function () {
                    var superBuffer = new Blob(chunks, {
                        type: 'audio/webm',
                    });

                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
                };
                recorder.start();
      })
      .catch((e) => {console.log(e);});
}
```

**popup.js:**

```
let btnStartTab = document.getElementById('start');
let btnStartTab1 = document.getElementById('stop');

btnStartTab.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ from: 'start' });
});

btnStartTab1.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ from: 'stop' });
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "My Recorer",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "test.png"
    },

    "commands": {
        "run-foo": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl + Shift + Y",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
            },
            "description": "Run \"foo\" on the current page."
        },
        "_execute_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl + Shift + Y",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
            }
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "declarativeContent",
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "tabCapture",
        "desktopCapture",
        "alarms",
        "activeTab",
        "downloads",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which script is throwing the error? Can you post your popup JS? Sidenote: It may be better to abandon Chrome extensions and build a [standards extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) instead (which will also work on Chrome)

Comment: @Mitya, I have updated the post above and its background.js which is giving the error.

Comment: How is your content script being loaded? Via the manifest or via injection? If the latter, can you show the code?

Comment: @Mitya, via Manifest, updated above

Comment: So the only difference I can see is that, in my solution, the content script that requests access is *injected*, via `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` and `chrome.runtime.getURL()`, as I describe in my answer (I talk about injecting a hidden iframe for this purpose). Other than that I don't know. You can download my Chrome Extension [ScreenRock](https://screenrock.com) and inspect the code if you want to dig deeper.

Comment: `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` worked but when I am accessing both `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({` and `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({` it again gives me same error

Comment: Apologies - I don't know, then. I can only suggest dig into my code and see how it's working there. It's some years now since I worked on this so my memory of it all is a bit sketchy.

Comment: Can you try putting `alert(location.href)` in your content script right before it requests device access and let us know the result?

Comment: @Mitya, gave me the address of current tab for example I was on google meets `https://meet.google.com/?authuser=1`

Comment: Right, that means you're running the content script in the context of the **page** not the **extension**. The latter is a must, and happens when you inject a content script with a URI returned via `chrome.runtime.getURL()`.

Comment: @Mitya, do I need to make some changes?

Comment: @Mitya, can you please help me with the above implementation.

Comment: You need to inject your content script (the one that asks for permsision) via `executeScript()`, as I have said. If you do that, rather than loading it via your manifest, it'll run in the context of the extension, *not* the current page. From this point I can only suggest you study the code behind my screenrock.com extension and see how it works there.

Comment: @Mitya, can you see this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088008/audio-goes-on-mute-as-i-start-recording-using-chrome-tabcapture-capture related to same

Comment: `meet.google.com`, eh? That's a web app that uses getUserMedia and getDisplay media itself. You need to rule out conflicts between your web extension and the code in `meet`.

Comment: @O.Jones, yeah trying to record on google.meets , but there are many extension that performs the same functionality.

Comment: @Mitya, I am trying to understand your codebase but getting the same. can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you confirm you are definitely loading the content script (the one that requests permission) via `chrome.tabs.executeScript(chrome.runtime.getURL('your-content-script.js'))` (in your background script), and *not* via the manifest?

Comment: @Mitya, I am getting this error `Error in event handler: TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.executeScript(optional integer tabId, extensionTypes.InjectDetails details, optional function callback): No matching signature.`

Comment: I have manifest updated above, thanks

Answer (score 6):

After deep searching and help from SO foundation found a way to reach the solution thought of sharing.

So, we need to understand that `background` doesn’t have control over DOM that's why we need to take help from `contentscript.js` and below architecture is important :

[image]

- In my case, I am injecting `contentscript.js` from manifest.json but one can use `executescript()` to inject the script.
- `contentscript.js` will create an iframe with display none with `iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL('audiosources.html');` above is important!!
- Also, `audiosources.html` is under `web_accessible_resources` in manifest.json
- The body of above HTML will have `<script src="audiosources.js"></script>` only.
- `audiosources.js` is the oe which will help to get rid of the error here I am getting access to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(...)` and all the mic devices. here on success it will send message to `background.js`.
- Now, `background.js` will do its magic of `tabCapture` with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` and here we need to apply logic for  merging.

Comment: @Gaurav why do you create an iframe? What does this iframe with audisource.[html,js] do as it is also not shown in your diagram (which is very helpful for understanding)?

Comment: Doing same approach, but I'm getting a NotAllowed error at the audiosources.js